# data.table update by reference for different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I tried to sets columns `trtxxp` and `trtxxa` as NA, when the `sdx` is NA.

dummy data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(sd1 = c(1:3, NA, 4:5, NA, 6:10, NA, NA),
                 sd2 = c(1:5, NA, 6:7, NA, NA, 10:13),
                 trt01p = "p", trt01a = "a",
                 trt02p = "p", trt02a = "a")
dt
    sd1 sd2 trt01p trt01a trt02p trt02a
 1:   1   1      p      a      p      a
 2:   2   2      p      a      p      a
 3:   3   3      p      a      p      a
 4:  NA   4      p      a      p      a
 5:   4   5      p      a      p      a
 6:   5  NA      p      a      p      a
 7:  NA   6      p      a      p      a
 8:   6   7      p      a      p      a
 9:   7  NA      p      a      p      a
10:   8  NA      p      a      p      a
11:   9  10      p      a      p      a
12:  10  11      p      a      p      a
13:  NA  12      p      a      p      a
14:  NA  13      p      a      p      a
```

I know I could achieved by below lines:

```
dt[is.na(sd1), `:=`(trt01p = NA,
                    trt01a = NA)]

dt[is.na(sd2), `:=`(trt02p = NA,
                    trt02a = NA)]
dt
    sd1 sd2 trt01p trt01a trt02p trt02a
 1:   1   1      p      a      p      a
 2:   2   2      p      a      p      a
 3:   3   3      p      a      p      a
 4:  NA   4   <NA>   <NA>      p      a
 5:   4   5      p      a      p      a
 6:   5  NA      p      a   <NA>   <NA>
 7:  NA   6   <NA>   <NA>      p      a
 8:   6   7      p      a      p      a
 9:   7  NA      p      a   <NA>   <NA>
10:   8  NA      p      a   <NA>   <NA>
11:   9  10      p      a      p      a
12:  10  11      p      a      p      a
13:  NA  12   <NA>   <NA>      p      a
14:  NA  13   <NA>   <NA>      p      a
```

But I since a got a lots of columns, so I tried with `.SD`, `lapply` and `.SDcols` but failed (only `trt01p` is update correctly)

```
trt.col <- c("trt01p", "trt01a", "trt02a", "trt02p")
sd.col <- c("sd1", "sd2")

dt[, (trt.col) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, get(trt.col))),
     .SDcols = sort(c(sd.col, sd.col))][]
dt
    sd1 sd2 trt01p trt01a trt02p trt02a
 1:   1   1      p      p      p      p
 2:   2   2      p      p      p      p
 3:   3   3      p      p      p      p
 4:  NA   4   <NA>   <NA>      p      p
 5:   4   5      p      p      p      p
 6:   5  NA      p      p   <NA>   <NA>
 7:  NA   6   <NA>   <NA>      p      p
 8:   6   7      p      p      p      p
 9:   7  NA      p      p   <NA>   <NA>
10:   8  NA      p      p   <NA>   <NA>
11:   9  10      p      p      p      p
12:  10  11      p      p      p      p
13:  NA  12   <NA>   <NA>      p      p
14:  NA  13   <NA>   <NA>      p      p
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: see ?setnafill which might satisfy your needs. otherwise, use a for loop and set()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MichaelChirico's suggest of a `for` loop may look like this:

```r
cols <- list(sd1=c("trt01p", "trt01a"), sd2=c("trt02a", "trt02p"))
for (col in names(cols)) set(dt, which(is.na(dt[[col]])), cols[[col]], value = NA)
dt
#       sd1   sd2 trt01p trt01a trt02p trt02a
#     <int> <int> <char> <char> <char> <char>
#  1:     1     1      p      a      p      a
#  2:     2     2      p      a      p      a
#  3:     3     3      p      a      p      a
#  4:    NA     4   <NA>   <NA>      p      a
#  5:     4     5      p      a      p      a
#  6:     5    NA      p      a   <NA>   <NA>
#  7:    NA     6   <NA>   <NA>      p      a
#  8:     6     7      p      a      p      a
#  9:     7    NA      p      a   <NA>   <NA>
# 10:     8    NA      p      a   <NA>   <NA>
# 11:     9    10      p      a      p      a
# 12:    10    11      p      a      p      a
# 13:    NA    12   <NA>   <NA>      p      a
# 14:    NA    13   <NA>   <NA>      p      a
```

(Though I think I'm missing a level of `data.table`-elegance somewhere.)

The named list is providing a sort of dependency: the *names* represent the columns that you want to test for `NA` values, and the *contents* for each of them are the columns that need to be updated in the presence of the condition.